# How to update child Component From Parent in separate files in react js

Tags: reactjs

Here's my example

```
// app.js
import {PostTitle} from './components/PostTitle.jsx';
function App() {
 render (
    <PostTitle data={data} />
)
}

// PostTitle.js
export function PostTitle({data}) {
    const [empty, updateEmpty] = useState(false);
    render (
       { empty && <div>component empty</div> }
    )
}
```

How to change **empty** to **true** from **App**

I try ref but it's confusing, may be is simplest way, because I have more than one child components

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to move this line `const [empty, updateEmpty] = useState(false);` in the parent component to check if the data is empty and set the state and pass that information as props to the child.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is define the state in the App file. Then, you can pass this state to your child component as a prop.